# Why do we see "function returned in array" syntax?

Tags: javascript

From time to time I see this sort of thing:

```
function functionCreator(p) {
    const newFunction = () => {
         console.log("Do stuff with p", p);
    }
    return [newFunction];
}

// later

function useIt(thing) {
   const [funky] = createFunction(thing);
   funky();
}
```

An example is [in this article about refs](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780#983b).

Why put the return value into an array, only to pluck it out again?

Comment: I guess some users just copy the behavior of `useState` which needs the array to return two values. Its unnecessary in this case however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the quantity of the values returned is **always** `1`, the tuple container unnecessarily complicates the calling code and (in most cases) wastefully creates a new array object on every invocation.

---

More on API interface design, if you're interested:

However, if the quantity of values returned is dynamic or greater than 1, a tuple is a useful choice over a "plain" object return type (which uses fixed property names) **when the API designer wants to give naming freedom to the consumer**. Consider this example:

The [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) API is commonly used to cancel async ops. However, the controller itself is much less commonly used than its [`signal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/signal) property and [`abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) method.

However, one cannot simply destructure them from the controller for subsequent use, because calling the unbound `abort` method is illegal:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const {abort, signal} = controller;
// equivalent to:
// const signal = conroller.signal;
// const abort = controller.abort;

signal.addEventListener('abort', () => console.log('aborted')); // ok

// controller.abort(); // ok (logs: "aborted")
abort(); // ⚠️ throws TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

The boilerplate for binding the method is straightforward, but not a one-liner destructure, and annoying to re-write over and over:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const {signal} = controller;
const abort = controller.abort.bind(controller);
// or, proxied:
// const abort = (reason) => controller.abort(reason);

signal.addEventListener('abort', () => console.log('aborted')); // ok

abort(); // ok (logs: "aborted")
```

This makes it a good candidate for creating with a factory (and I'll go ahead and write that factory as a custom hook):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBZNIIBo6poDKMAhjGgL5wBmUEIcA5FGqQMYxMDcAULzSQA7TsAhCC6AIIAjaDCLAA5kNIAbOAAoAlAC5EvOHBTLVa-bPmKV63Ibik5sfZtakU4gPz7hAayEQAO5C2nAAvAB8cABuEMAAJnZGrOxuFC6hkTFxibzUCPbs4ijwANpFQjD0ampoUPjoMADC4lUQNXUAuuGSxGQUmkJogXCWsC2V1bVQOtp8yWgwSFAShFg4mjrhUZoFRkYmNuZwFW0dUAB0h2ZJ+47y+m4eElmnU3UX97CubM-atwtUmx0lpMlFGhMztNBsNRk5mq13jNtP97JR-nByoj2tNOnM8vxBCIYGIJC1wOI0JVQQYjBUSohrup9Ey1ABGfBfGD6Lls6hhXpjBSmdQ6eYnYrwBCslkitQAJk58J58Pl-MF8OsZjF-CMAHo9XAAKroODACRFClDSoXW15IA)

```ts
import {useMemo, useState} from 'react';

function useAbortSignal (): {
  signal: AbortSignal,
  abort: (reason?: unknown) => void,
  recreate: () => void,
} {
  const [controller, setController] = useState(new AbortController());
  return useMemo(() => ({
    signal: controller.signal,
    abort: reason => controller.abort(reason),
    recreate: () => setController(new AbortController()),
  }), [controller]);
}
```

And using it looks like this:

```ts
function Component () {
  const {signal, abort} = useAbortSignal();

  // Use in component...
}
```

So, that's simple, but what if we need more than one unique signal in the same component for multiple, unrelated ops?

```ts
function Component () {
  const {signal, abort} = useAbortSignal();
  //     ~~~~~~  ~~~~~
  const {signal, abort} = useAbortSignal(); /*
         ~~~~~~  ~~~~~
  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'signal'.(2451)
  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'abort'.(2451) */

  // Use in component...
}
```

We can't destructure the same property names, so we have to rename them:

```ts
function Component () {
  const {signal: signal1, abort: abort1} = useAbortSignal();
  const {signal: signal2, abort: abort2} = useAbortSignal();

  // Use in component...
}
```

That works, but it's not very ergonomic.

The answer to this is using a tuple return type for the hook:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBZNIIBo6poDKMAhjGgL5wBmUEIcA5FGqQMYxMDcAULzSQA7TsAhCC6AIIAjaDCLAA5kNIAbOAAoAlAC44AbV5w4KZarX7Z8xSvW5jcUnNj7NrUinEB+fcIDWQhAA7kLacAC8AHxwAG4QwAAmDias7B4UbuHRcQnJvAC6iI7s4ijwBqVCMPRqamhQ+OgwAMLiNRB1DUURksRkFJpCaMFw1rBt1bX1UDrafKloMEhQEoRYOJo6kTFGJiZVHV1QAHRmdmop+x5eEjmH0w0nzvLubLfaVybbOc2TRzMhiMxi5Wu1HrNtJ9HAV8JVwZ0ZgV5rxKPxBCIYGIJG1wOI0NUtOEECUyhVzhYAIz4F6wSk9PrjBTmdQ6BZwKrlQwU9QAJhpoN5DMITNsFjZ-BMAHopXAAKroODACSlPHDaonTWooA)

```ts
import {useMemo, useState} from 'react';

function useAbortSignal (): [
  signal: AbortSignal,
  abort: (reason?: unknown) => void,
  recreate: () => void,
] {
  const [controller, setController] = useState(new AbortController());
  return useMemo(() => [
    controller.signal,
    reason => controller.abort(reason),
    () => setController(new AbortController()),
  ], [controller]);
}
```

So, when using it, the **names** of the destructured members don't matter, only the **order**:

```ts
function Component () {
  const [signal1, abort1] = useAbortSignal();
  const [signal2, abort2] = useAbortSignal();

  // Use in component...
}
```

which is less code to type, **and** gives you the freedom to name your variables how you please — which, of course, is [a double-edged sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))...

While the `AbortController` API is occasionally needed more than once in a scope, it is extremely common for `useState` to be invoked multiple times in a component, so a tuple choice is fitting as a return type.

Hopefully that gives you some context on one consideration involved in API interface design.